# Sending array as callbackdata in JS from PHP

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

I have a dashboard page to display last five days attendance data getting from database.For that,from script im calling a function which i defined in seperate .js file. Using php function,im sending the data back to Javascript function as callbackdata. Im in Javascript, i dont know how to process this array data. Actually i got this idea from one sample application,working fine with strings but i could not code for the arrays.
Index.php page

```
       <div class="inner">                              
            <table  class="table table-borderless table-condensed ">
            <thead><tr><th>Date</th><th>Total</th></tr></thead>
            <tbody id ="attendancelist">                    
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <script>
    modJs.getlastfiveattendance(); 
   </script>
```

JS File:

```
Display.method('getlastfiveattendance', function() {
    var that = this;
    var object = {"emp_id":empId};  
    var reqJson = JSON.stringify(object);
    var callBackData = [];
    callBackData['callBackData'] = [];
    callBackData['callBackSuccess'] = 'getlastPunchSuccessCallBack';
    callBackData['callBackFail'] = 'getlastPunchFailCallBack';  
    this.customAction('getLastfive','modules=attendance',reqJson,callBackData);
});

Display.method('getlastPunchSuccessCallBack', function(callBackData) {  
    var punches = callBackData; 
    $('#attendancelist').html('');
    var row = '<tr><td>_date_</td><td>_total_</td></tr>';   

    $.each( punches, function(key, value) {  //here i have to process this array to get each data
    var trow = row;     
        trow = trow.replace(/_date_/g,Date.parse(key).toString('MMM d, yyyy (dddd)'));
        trow = trow.replace(/_total_/g,value);
        html += trow;   
    });
    $('#attendancelist').html(html);        

});    
Display.method('getlastPunchFailCallBack', function(callBackData) {     
    this.showMessage("error","Failed to Retrieve data");        
});
```

In PHP file, im getting data and passing it as array,just i need date and total hours on that particular date.

```
public function getLastfive($req){          
        empid = $req->emp_id;           
        $attendance = new Attendance();
        $attendanceList = $attendance->Find("employee = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5",array(empid));          
        $dayMap = array();          
        foreach($attendanceList as $attendance){
            $dayMap[$attendance->in_time] = $attendance->note; //emp in_time as key and the total time as value
        }   
        return new simRes(simRes::SUCCESS,$dayMap);         
    }
```

But here the control doesnt get in to $.each loop. WHen i check by the following code to check the punches is array or not,by using below code. IT shows as not array.

```
if( Object.prototype.toString.call( punches ) === '[object Array]' ) {
    this.showMessage("yes","It's array");
    }
    else
        this.showMessage("No","Its no array");
```

Inside simRes class:

```
class SimRes{   
    const SUCCESS = "SUCCESS";
    const ERROR = "ERROR";  
    var $status;
    var $data;
    public function __construct($status,$data = null){
        $this->status = $status;    
        $this->data = $data;    
    }   
    public function getStatus(){
        return $this->status;
    }   
    public function getData(){
        return $this->data;
    }   
    public function getJsonArray(){
        return array("status"=>$this->status,"data"=>$this->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: new simRes(simRes::SUCCESS,$dayMap);  - it responds with json? can You give response example?

Comment: do this: Display.method('getlastPunchSuccessCallBack', function(callBackData) {   console.log(callBackData);    open inspector panel and give us result of console.log

Comment: It shows as 'null' in inspector panel

Comment: can You edit Your question and give the code inside of class simRes ?

Comment: and also the body of customAction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

In Your PHP part:

```
public function getLastfive($req){          
    $attendance = new Attendance();
    $attendanceList = $attendance->Find("employee = ? ORDERBY id DESC LIMIT 5)",array((int)$req->emp_id));    
    $dayMap = array();   
    // generating array of attendances with key value
    foreach($attendanceList as $attendance){
        $dayMap[] = [
            'date' => $attendance->in_time,
            'total' => $attendance->note
        ];
    }

    return new simRes(simRes::SUCCESS, json_encode($dayMap)); // I don't know if it's already json-ifies result, but if Yes, so remove json_encode
}
```

In Your HTML (include lodash lib, it simplifies working with JS):

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash/4.6.1/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

and in Your JS code:

```
Display.method('getlastPunchSuccessCallBack', function(callBackData) { 
    $('#attendancelist').html(''); // making empty before processing data

    // if response is string, it happens when You don't send application/json content type on response headers
    if(_.isString(callBackData)) {
        callBackData = JSON.parse(callBackData); // parse string make it json
    }
    if(!_.isArray(callBackData)) { // if it's not array of objects, so stop here
        return;
    }

    var punches = callBackData;

    var html = ''; // create empty var to generate html
    _.each(punches, function(punch) { 
        // iterate array of punches and pass punch to iterator function
        // punch is object like {date: "some date", total: "some value"}

        html+='<tr>';
        html+='<td>'+Date.parse(punch.date).toString('MMM d, yyyy (dddd)')+'</td>';
        html+='<td>'+punch.total+'</td>';
        html+='</tr>';
    });

    $('#attendancelist').html(html);   
});
```

Comment: there can be problems with code, cuz have not tested, but You can understand logic

Comment: i tried this code by changing PHP database query,actually there is mistake.Now when i see in inspector panel,console.log prints all data in format : [{"date":"2016-01-29 08:45:17","total":"09:31:37"},{"date":"2016-01-28 08:58:25","total":"09:49:23"},{"date":"2016-01-27 08:55:48","total":"09:27:35"},{"date":"2016-01-25 09:07:25","total":"08:59:10"},{"date":"2016-01-23 09:14:33","total":"07:11:44"}]